# Add Environment variable to Hudson

Tags: hudson

I am looking into a way of defining an environment variable for Hudson (NCover path on build server), so that build scripts can use it, but no need to re-define it in Hudson jobs (similar to `%SVN_REVISION%` or `%BUILD_NUMBER%`). What would be the way of doing it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set node variables, that will be available to every job that runs on that node.   Go to the node configuration page, and you'll see it.   For the master node, the environment variables are configured on Hudson's main configuration screen.

Comment: To be precise, the environment variables configured under Manage Hudson -> Configure System apply to every build on every node, not just the master.

Answer (score 2):

If it's global (same on every node), you can add environment variables for every build in Manage Hudson -> Configure System, under Global Properties -> Environment Variables

Updated: Oops, sorry, didn't notice that @Michael Donohue had already said this.